# How to search and highlight text in PDF using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, pdf, com, highlight, acrobat

Right, so after hours of searching; I've come up with nothing for excel vba, which I find surprising. Found some vbs that I tried to port over but no luck. I have managed to import the pdf text into sheets and search it, which is good; but this won't allow me to actually highlight the pdf obviously.

What I'm trying to do is open up PDF docs, search them for keywords and then highlight those words and save. I've got adobe acrobat X, so there must be some sort of API that will allow me to do this with excel vba? Am I going to have to use some sort of opensource library like iText; I would prefer not to.

Some of the vbs that I saw involved finding text letter by letter and then drawing rectangles around it and colouring with javascript and that just seemed unnecessarily complicated (couldn't get the port to work anyway...).

**CLARIFICATION:**
I don't want to highlight the text in excel, I want to highlight it on the PDF. I am only reading it into Excel to search for the text and see if its in the PDF, since I don't know how else to do this.

PS: It would also be nice to be able to use OCR on image pdfs.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, played a little bit around with the code I already have had and js annots.
Attached you will find a VBScript which can mark/highlight a word permanent. It can easily be changed to mark also more as only one word. In the AcroJS help file you can find some options for the markers outfit.

The VBS code I wrote VBA like. So you can copy it direct into your IDE.

Enjoy, Reinhard

```
 '// Save this as xxx.vbs and start with Double Click
 '// Acrobat must be opend before with an active document!! -otherwise error-

wordTF = "Reinhard" '//word to find
pdfText = ""

set WshShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate("Adobe Acrobat")
WScript.Sleep 500

'// get the active Document
Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set AVDoc = AcroApp.GetActiveDoc
Set PDDoc = AVDoc.GetPDDoc
Set AForm = CreateObject("AFormAut.App") 'connect to Form API for later use

maxPages = PdDoc.GetNumPages
for p = 0 to maxPages - 1  '// start the page loop
    Set PdfPage = PDDoc.AcquirePage(p) '// p  = Pagenumber (zero based)
    Set PageHL = CreateObject("AcroExch.HiliteList")  '// created to get the page text
    PageHLRes = PageHL.Add(0,9000) '<<--SET in FILE! (Start,END[9000=All])
    Set PageSel = PdfPage.CreatePageHilite(PageHL)

    for i = 0 to PageSel.Getnumtext - 1   '// start the word loop on current page
        word = PageSel.getText(i)         '// get one word
        pdfText = pdfText & word          '// gather words on page

        if instr(word, wordTF) then       '// used instr because the "word" you may get as "word "
            msgbox("add:""" &word &"""")                Set wordToHl = CreateObject("AcroExch.HiliteList") '// created to get the word on list
            wordToHl.Add i, 1 'Hilite the word Reinhard
            Set wordHl = PdfPage.CreateWordHilite(wordToHl)
            Set rect = wordHl.GetBoundingRect
            msgbox("left:" &rect.Left &" bot:" &rect.bottom &" right:"&rect.Right &" top:" &rect.Top)
            AVDoc.SetTextSelection(wordHl)  '// highlight the word (not really needed)
            AVDoc.ShowTextSelect()          '// show highlighted text (not really needed)
              '// write and execute js to mark permanent (to lazy to translate to jso)
            ex = " // set annot for text selection " &vbLf _
                & "var sqannot = this.addAnnot({type: ""Square"", page: 1, " &vbLf _
                & "rect: [" &rect.left &", "& rect.top &", " &rect.right &", " &rect.bottom &"], " &vbLf _
                & "name: ""p" &p &"i" &i &"""});"
            msgbox(ex)
            AForm.Fields.ExecuteThisJavaScript ex
        end if '// word found
    Next  '// get next word
    msgBox(pdfText)
    pdfText = ""
next '// get next page
msgbox("Done!")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that code sample from the future!

Comment: Set wordHl = PdfPage.CreateWordHilite(wordToHl)   -  it returns nothing. what can we do?

Answer (score 0):

There are some possibilities to remote control Acrobat. On Mac, it is via AppleScript, and on Windows, it is via VB/VBS (if I remember correctly). In any case, you then have the possibility to run Acrobat JavaScript.

You might download the Acrobat SDK from the Adobe website, and look through the Documentation folder.

Despite the not so good experiences, this is kind of the way to go: loop through all pages of the document, loop through all the "words" on the actual page, read out the coordinates of the bounding box of the found word (also known as "quads"), maybe do some comparisons with other "words", to figure out whether these "words" do belong together. Finally create a Highlight Annotation using as coordinates the read out quads.

Another possibility for finding words in a PDF document would be using the markup part of the Redaction tool (stop the redaction process before the removing and writing back of the redacted document happens). Then you would run an Acrobat JavaScript enumerating all the Redaction type annotations, and replace them with similar Highlight annotations.

Comment: Thanks @Max Wyss, is it not at all possible to expose Acrobat Reader's built in search tool?

Comment: It seems like i should be able to do this via IAC

Comment: I think so too, that's a way to follow. Good luck!

Comment: Easier said than done! I can't believe there is no example out there to exactly do what I want. This must be such a common requirement!

Comment: I agree, there are rather few code samples in the documentation… I could help if it were with AppleScript…